# SELECT INTO using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00905

I'm trying to do a SELECT INTO using Oracle. My query is:

```
SELECT * INTO new_table FROM old_table;
```

But I get the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

---

The Standard behavior of the above should be as I originally thought:
However Oracle implemented it totally differently in their own dialect of SQL
[Oracle Docs on Insert ... Select](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/insert-select.html)

Comment: `select into` to create a new table is *not* part of the standard. The SQL standard to create a table based on a select is `create table .. as select ...`. In the SQL standard `SELECT INTO` is defined to read a column value into a variable in a programming language

Comment: Here's a working link to the Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423__I2145074
(NOTE: With oracle documentation having a working link is a moving target)
(NOTE2: "Too many pending edits on stackoverflow..." or I would have edited.

Answer (score 325, accepted):

If NEW_TABLE already exists then ...

```
insert into new_table 
select * from old_table
/
```

If you want to create NEW_TABLE based on the records in OLD_TABLE ...

```
create table new_table as 
select * from old_table
/
```

If the purpose is to create a new but empty table then use a WHERE clause with a condition which can never be true:

```
create table new_table as 
select * from old_table
where 1 = 2
/
```

Remember that CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT creates only a table with the same projection as the source table. The new table does not have any constraints, triggers or indexes which the original table might have. Those still have to be added manually (if they are required).

Comment: +1 @Robert: Plus, if you just want to copy the schema of old_table, use a negative where clause, like for instance: create new_table as select * from old_table WHERE 1=2.

Answer (score 40):

`select into` is used in pl/sql to set a variable to field values.  Instead, use

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table
```

Comment: I though SELECT INTO was part of the Standard. Did Oracle do something strange here or was it never part of the standard?

Comment: `select into` is part of pl/sql. It is a language for writing stored procedures and has no direct relation to sql standard. And yes, Oracle made many things that were never part of the standard =)

Comment: @RobertGould: no, `SELECT INTO ` is *not* standard SQL. The standard only defines `create table .. as select ..`

Comment: SELECT INTO IS part of standard SQL see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Like many other parts of standard SQL Oracle does its own thing.

Comment: @grahamhanson that appears to be a link to the W3Schools tutorial site, not an ANSI standards document.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
create table new_table_name 
as
select column_name,[more columns] from Existed_table;
```

Example:

```
create table dept
as
select empno, ename from emp;
```

If the table already exists:

```
insert into new_tablename select columns_list from Existed_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this below statement instead of using select into in oracle:

select * from(select * from table1) table2  ;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).