# Creating Duplicate Table From Existing Table

Tags: oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [SELECT INTO using Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle)

I have one table in my oracle database. I want to create one table with another name, but containing same data. How to achieve this ?

Comment: I do not consider this as duplicate, since this question is how humans ask. The referenced question already contains a part of the solution in the question.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Use this query to create the new table with the values from existing table

```
CREATE TABLE New_Table_name AS SELECT * FROM Existing_table_Name;
```

Now you can get all the values from existing table into newly created table.

Comment: if you just want an empty table then :   
CREATE TABLE  new_table
  AS (SELECT * FROM  old_table where rownum = 0);

Comment: It does NOT duplicate constraints

Comment: Also it does not duplicate default values, nor comments

Comment: It also does not duplicate partitions or grants.

Comment: It also does not duplicate triggers.