# How can I create table as select (CTAS) in oracle?

Tags: sql, indexing, oracle10g, foreign-keys, composite-key

I need to use `CTAS (Create Table As Select)` to create a table named `Au_Books_ZL` that contains `au_id, fname, lname, title_id, title, Pub_id, price and revenue (which is price*sales)`.

I have browsed other questions online, but they don't show how to include all the attributes (lname, fname, title_id ect.) in the query. How could I write up my CTAS to create the new table?

Comment: Please only ask one thing in a single StackOverflow question.  I removed a few unrelated questions from this post-- feel free to ask those as separate questions.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for creating a table would be something like

```
CREATE TABLE au_books_zl
AS
  SELECT au_id,
         fname,
         lname,
         title_id,
         title,
         pub_id,
         price,
         price * sales as revenue
    FROM <<whatever tables you need to select from>>
   WHERE <<whatever conditions you need to apply>>
```

Comment: this will just create the table or table along with data ?

Comment: @JustTry - You could just try it :-)  But it will create the table and populate it with whatever data the query returns.