# Creating new table with SELECT INTO in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select, create-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SELECT INTO using Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle)

I have came across `SQL SELECT INTO` statement for creating new table and also dumping old table records into new table in single SQL statement as

```
  SELECT * INTO NEW_TABLE FROM OLD_TABLE;
```

But when i am trying the above query it is giving error as `ORA-00905: missing keyword`

Is it possible to do that in ORACLE ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

The syntax for creating a new table is

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS
SELECT *
  FROM old_table
```

This will create a new table named `new_table` with whatever columns are in `old_table` and copy the data over.  It will not replicate the constraints on the table, it won't replicate the storage attributes, and it won't replicate any triggers defined on the table.

`SELECT INTO` is used in PL/SQL when you want to fetch data from a table into a local variable in your PL/SQL block.

Comment: To complete the picture: `create table as ..` is standard SQL and supported by nearly all DBMS. Even some of those that use SELECT INTO to create new tables.

Comment: Doesn't work in SQL Server Management Studio.