# Select into with max()

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, max

I have a basic query I use to determine the max value of a column in a table:

```
select A.revenue_code_id, max(A.revenue_code_version) from rev_code_lookup A
group by A.revenue_code_id
```

This results in ~580 rows (the entire table has over 2400 rows).

This works just fine for my query results but what I don't know is how to insert the 580 rows into a new able based on the max value.  I realize this isn't the right code but what I am thinking of would look something like this:

```
select * into new_table from rev_code_lookup where max(revenue_code_version)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SELECT INTO using Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle)

Comment: this is not for Oracle, next time I'll be sure to specify SQL server to avoid confusion.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `row_number()` function to get the data you want. Combine with the other answer to insert the results into a table (I've made up a couple of extra columns as an example):

```
Select
  x.revenue_code_id,
  x.revenue_code_version,
  x.update_timestamp,
  x.updated_by
From (
  Select
    revenue_code_id,
    revenue_code_version,
    update_timestamp,
    updated_by,
    row_number() over (partition by revenue_code_id Order By revenue_code_version Desc) as rn
  From
    revenue_code_lookup
) x
Where
  x.rn = 1
```

[Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38260/1)

Comment: Thanks, that got what I needed.  There are a few things in there I have not seen/used before so I am going to learn about them.

Answer (score 1):

The insert in another table is always the same way, no matter the complexity of your select:

```
insert into table
[unbeliavablycomplicatedselecthere]
```

So in your case:

```
insert into new_table
select A.revenue_code_id, max(A.revenue_code_version) from rev_code_lookup A
group by A.revenue_code_id
```

Similarly, if you need to create a brand new table, do this first:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
AS
select A.revenue_code_id, max(A.revenue_code_version) from rev_code_lookup A
group by A.revenue_code_id
```

This will create the corresponding table schema and then you can execute the previous query to insert the data.

Comment: OK, and what if I have two other fields to add to my insert statement?  I have 4 total fields in the source table, one is a text and the other is a date.  But I need to insert based on the revenue_code_version max value.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't matter how complex your query, the pattern is the same. So just change your query and add it at the end of `create table as` as well as `insert into`.

Comment: When I did the following, I got ALL rows inserted into the destination from the source, not just the max.  I obviously have something wrong...

'select A.revenue_code_id, max(revenue_code_version) AS revenue_code_version,
description, last_updated 
INTO rev_code2
from rev_code_lookup A
group by A.revenue_code_id, description, last_updated
order by max(revenue_code_version) desc'

Comment: Sorry, I just now realized your issue was not with the syntax of the INSERT INTO but the issue was with max. See @Laurence's answer in that case.