# Error while using the select into statement

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to use select into statement to copy contents from one table to another.

```
select* into xyz from xyz_123 where id = 100
```

but while executing I'm getting an error

```
ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 15
```

please help me fix this error

Answer (score 3):

If table `xyz` already exists use this:

```
INSERT INTO xyz
SELECT * FROM xyz_123 WHERE id = 100
```

If table `xyz` does *not* yet exist, then create it:

```
CREATE TABLE xyz
AS SELECT * FROM xyz_123 WHERE id = 100
```

By the way, if you spend a little time searching Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle), as well as one other site [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php), then you can piece this answer together yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not correct syntax if you are executing it alone. Use like below.

```
insert into xyz 
select * from xyz_123 where id = 100;
```