# Create a Table in Oracle, Update Data Type, Insert Into with Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba

I am trying to create a new table in oracle but I am getting these errors with their respective attempts:

**FAILED CREATE:**

1)

```
CREATE TABLE quicktemp (LN_ID VARCHAR(255))
```

Err : "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis"

2)

```
CREATE TABLE quicktemp VALUES (LN_ID VARCHAR(255))
```

Err : "ORA-00922: missing or invalid option"

**SUCCESSFUL CREATE, FAILED DATA TYPE on INSERT INTO:**

3)

```
CREATE TABLE quicktemp AS (SELECT LN_ID FROM dual WHERE 1 = 0)

INSERT INTO quicktemp (LN_ID) WITH temp AS (
    SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 FROM dual 
    )
    SELECT * FROM temp
```

Err : ORA-01790: expression must have same datatype as corresponding expression

My three options are to **1)** create a table to allow any datatypes, **2)** update a created table (with method 3) to allow for any data type or **3)** change the datatypes of the values I am trying to insert. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**PROJECT SUMMARY:**

The data is being queried from one database, exported to an Excel file, and then imported into a new table in a different database. I am picking up the field names and the values from the newly created Excel worksheet. I am not planning on using existing tables since they either don't exist, or I can't access them with the current schema.

NB: This project needs to be done entirely in VBA. I cannot accept answers relating to SSIS, SQL*Loader, etc.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle

Comment: And I think you should use `VARCHAR2` rather than `VARCHAR`

Comment: VARCHAR2 is the data type for dual I believe. Will that accept any data?