# How do I create a new table from query results?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the code I am using;

```
select A.CD, A.NM
from TABLE A, TABLE B
where A.CD=B.CD
and A.NM <> B.NM;
```

And I want to create a table named "NEW_TABLE" having the above query results.
(The above code means that I am selecting rows that are equal in the column "CD" but different in the column "NM")

I tried;

```
create table NEW_TABLE    
select A.CD, A.NM
from TABLE A, TABLE B
where A.CD=B.CD
and A.NM <> B.NM;
```

But the script says that there is a missing keyword.. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SELECT INTO using Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle)

Comment: @Hooman, it is not duplicated as OP ask for create, not insert results in to existing table

Comment: The answer in that post does not work. Error message pops up as follows: "unable to extend temp segment by %s in tablesapce %s".

Comment: *Cause : Failed to allocate an extent of the required number of blocks for a temporary segment in the tablespace indicated.

Comment: *Action : Use ALTER TABLESPACE ADD DATAFILE statement to add one or more files to the tablesapce indicated

Comment: @Rubertos in such case please consult your DBA (or extend TEMP tablespace by self)

Comment: How do I extend TEMP tablespace by myself? (I dunno what "TEMP" tablespace is though..)

Comment: Please refer to Oracle documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tspaces007.htm#ADMIN11364

Comment: In the linked question, it's not clear whether the need is inserting into an axisting table or creating a new one, but the accepted answer gives both solutions. So this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `AS` keyword:

```
create table NEW_TABLE 
AS (select A.CD, A.NM
from TABLE A, TABLE B
where A.CD=B.CD
and A.NM <> B.NM);
```

Comment: @Rubertos check my comment to the question