# SQL query to insert data from one table into a non existing table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Suppose I have a table `Demo` with 4 columns and 50 entries. I want to create the backup of `Demo` in `Demo2` which does not yet exist. Until now, I was trying this..

```
Create table DEMO2
(
  ..
  ..
  ..
);
```

After that I used this query..

```
INSERT INTO DEMO2
    SELECT * 
    FROM DEMO;
```

which works fine but I want to create the backup without creating second table `DEMO2`.

How can I do it?

Comment: u can create  like this ..select * into DEMO2  from Demo

Comment: I tried it.. it says "missing keyword"

Comment: what you tried just try with this select * into DEMO2 from Demo  it will work..
MSSQL or oracle you are using

Comment: It is still saying :Missing Keyword".. I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: do not use `sql-server` tag as it is confusing

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. This question has been asked before - please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle

Comment: Thanks i got the answer from this link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If NEW_TABLE already exists then

```
insert into new_table select * from old_table
```

If you want to create NEW_TABLE based on the records in OLD_TABLE

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table
```

Comment: I tried it, It says "missing Keyword"

Comment: It must not say "Missing Keywords", could you please share your query here?

Comment: That is invalid for Oracle.

Comment: sql server answer to an oracle question, i'm afraid..

Comment: The required query was.. 'create table new_table as select * from old_table'

Comment: excuse me but don't use sql-server tags it is confusing