# PL\SQL - Get counts of all tables in a schema - errors

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, count

I want to get a result: table name, count amount for each table from AS_TABLE_LIST.

```
create procedure AtRowCount
as
declare
TableCount NUMBER(1);
TableName VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
SelectQuery1:= 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || TableName || ' INTO ' ||             TableCount;
FOR TableName IN (select table_name from AS_TABLE_LIST) 
LOOP
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SelectQuery1;
END LOOP;
select TableName, TableCount into AT_ROW_COUNT from dual;
END AtRowCount;
```

I get two errors:

> [Error] PLS-00306 (7: 19): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of
>   arguments in call to '||'
>
> [Error] ORA-00904 (9: 8): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "TABLENAME": invalid
>   identifier

I've been trying many times to fix this but still got same errors.
any advice?

Comment: I see many issues here; try to build your procedure step by step, by starting with a procedure that only does `begin null; end;`. Then add variables and statements. A [starting point](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-PROCEDURE.html#GUID-771879D8-BBFD-4D87-8A6C-290102142DA3)

Comment: Please show a [mcve].  You have a lot of issues here, but cannot review without a complete example.  Where is AS_TABLE_LIST created and populated, etc.

Comment: what is your aim in here `'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || TableName || ' INTO ' ||             TableCount;`..?.. If creating a new table from `Tablename`, then must [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle)

Comment: Hmm. Is AT_ROW_COUNT a table? Do you want your results to go into a table, or be printed to the screen, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying todo, but it might be the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AtRowCount AS
DECLARE
  l_count NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR c IN (SELECT table_name from AS_TABLE_LIST) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '||c.table_name INTO l_count;
    INSERT INTO AT_ROW_COUNT(TableName, TableCount )
    VALUES (c.table_name, l_count);
  END LOOP;
END AtRowCount;
```

If you want you're procedure to return the list instead of inserting the result in a new table, you have to use a pipelined function instead (see https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions for an example on how to use it).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all rows count against table name in oracle by:

```
select owner, table_name, nvl(num_rows,-1) 
from all_tables 
order by nvl(num_rows,-1) desc
```

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_EPJLBHYMPOPAGL9PQAV7XH14Q.html

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work for you

```
            CREATE PROCEDURE atrowcount
            IS 
             selectquery1 VARCHAR2(2000);
             tablecount NUMBER;
            BEGIN
                selectquery1:= 'SELECT count(1) FROM :TableName';
               FOR i IN (select table_name from AS_TABLE_LIST) 
               LOOP
                   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE selectquery1 INTO tablecount USING i.table_name;
                   INSERT INTO table_list VALUES(i.table_name,TableCount);
               END LOOP;
               COMMIT;
            END AtRowCount;
```

Comment: Have you tried it? That cannot work, as you cannot bind the tablename to a query. The statement must be parsable without doing the binding and therefore it is imposible to bind the table at runtime...