# Spring Scheduled task stops running when long running findAll() repository method is called

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data, hikaricp, spring-scheduled

I have Spring Boot 2 application with Spring Data. This is database connection definition:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX:9555:YYY
spring.datasource.username=uname
spring.datasource.password=pwd

spring.datasource.hikari.connection-test-query=SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=5
spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=pool
```

Then I have a cron scheduled job defined like this:

```
@Async
@Scheduled(cron = "${calculate.cron}")
public void calculate() {
    try {
        if (syncInstancesForTaskExecution()) {
            calculatorService.calculate();
            // Remove task start execution DT
            instanceSyncService.setTaskLastExecutionDt(null);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Scheduled task failed", e);
    }
```

This is calculate method in CalculatorService:

```
public void calculateRequests() {
        logger.trace("Task deleting old data");
        calculatedRepository.deleteAll();
        logger.trace("Task deleted old data");

        logger.trace("Task selecting new data");
        Iterable<ServiceRequestView> srv = viewRepository.findAll();
        logger.trace("Task selected new data");
...
```

Logic behind the scheduled job is that it basically runs every night, deletes the old data from the table (`calculatedRepository.deleteAll()`), selects the new data from the database view (`viewRepository.findAll()`) and then saves the new data in the table.

Problem which I am experiencing is that sometimes the execution hangs after a `viewRepository.findAll()` is called. On the database we can see that the select was called and executed. For now, to me, it looks like if the execution of the select takes less then 1 hour then everything goes fine, and if the select takes longer then 1 hour to execute then the problem occurs.

There is no any error present in the logs, and the only thing that I can see is that the logging stops after the `findAll()` has been called and a next log line (`logger.trace("Task selected new data")`) is never printed. I can also see that the update on the database was not performed, so its not just that the logging does not work, but it looks like whole task execution stops/ends.

Do you know that could cause this problem? Datasource, Hikari Pool, Scheduled job or what? I cant find the reason.

**EDIT:**
I have updated the code as suggested by [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) - implemented the `DELETE FROM table` and `INSERT INTO ...` but the problem still remains. The `INSERT INTO ...` query is executed after 1 hour and 2 minutes, but nothing is inserted in the table and the log again looks the same. :(

Comment: The way you are writing your code. Instead of delete use a `TRUNCATE` and instead of retrieving everything and then storing everything write a `SELECT ... INTO` query which does allt his in 1 go. Will be a lot faster and will use way less memory.

Comment: Thanks, I will implemented it that way. That will fix performance, but why do you think it causes this particular issue where the code just hangs?

Comment: Because the `findAll` will load every record into memory. So if you have 1000000 rows hibernate needs to fetch all of them, create objects and then you will insert them 1 by 1 (even when using a `saveAll`). You are probably not using batching (i.e. 50 or 100 each time) leading to exesive dirty checks in a single transaction.

Comment: OK. But in this case the code hangs before there is a call to `saveAll()`, which should happen after the log `logger.trace("Task selected new data")` is printed. And the log is never printed, it hangs before that line.

Comment: I have implemented the `DELETE FROM table` and `INSERT INTO ...` but it is still not working. The `INSERT INTO ...` query is executed after 1 hour and 2 minutes, but nothing is inserted in the table and the log again looks the same. :(

Comment: You obviously haven't read my comment. I didn't say an `INSERT INTO` I said an `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: I really did read the comment and have done some more research to understand the behavior of the `findAll()` and `deleteAll()`. But [I cant execute such SQL statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250196/select-into-using-oracle), that is why I have changed it. Since `INSERT INTO` also should not return any objects to the application it should also consume less memory. But the problem still remains, if the call to the database layer lasts longer then 60 minutes it hangs forever...

Comment: Furthermore, I can see that the scheduled thread which is executing the code is still running  2 and more hours after the initial start, since it does not start again when it should (updated the cron expression to start it every hour) when I remove `@Async` annotation.

Comment: If that still hangs there must be something really wrong in  your setup, which is impossible to tell from here.

Comment: I have tried few more times and concentrated on the Hikari pool and connections. I can see that the session which executes `INSERT INTO` statement is ACTIVE on Oracle DB until the statement is finished and then it is removed from the DB. While the statement is running Hikari pool debug log always has 1 or more active connections. After the stamen is finished and session removed from DB, Hikari pool still sees 1 permanent active connection, although the Oracle DB does not see it in the sessions.

Comment: It is a pool so it has multiple connections open to the database (unless you configured it otherwise). Also how are you executing the statement?

Comment: What looks to me strange is this: When app starts - `HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=0, idle=10, waiting=0)`, Oracle `V$SESSION` shows 10 inactive sessions. While statement runs `HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)`, Oracle `V$SESSION` shows 9 inactive and one active sessions. When statement finishes - `HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)`, Oracle `V$SESSION` shows 9 inactive sessions. 10th connection is then not recreated by Hikari, not in the next few minutes or hours. Hikari keeps seeing 1 active session.

Comment: To execute a query I am using Spring Data (JPA) repository interface and a method annotated likes this:  `@Modifying
 @Query(value = "INSERT INTO calculated SELECT * FROM v_calculated", nativeQuery = true)
 void calculateAndSaveNewData();`

Comment: I forgot to add that I have commented out `spring.datasource.hikari` properties for this few runs, so that is why the Hikari connection pool is larger then what I defined by the properties.

Comment: Further update, I have found out that a thread which executed the statement is hanging at `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0`. Still don't understand the root cause of this.

Comment: The default poolsize is 10. Also make sure your service method is `@Transactional` and try to figure out using your normal SQL tooling how fast (or slow) the query would be. Shouldn't take that long (generally) unless your view is a complex one with a lot of joins etc.

Comment: I'm aware that the default pool size is 10. I was talking about discrepancy where Hikari sees 1 and Oracle DB 0 active connections. A view is rather complex and processes millions of records. Query takes the same time to execute from the SQL tool like TOAD and from application (currently around 65 minutes). Problem is when the execution takes longer than 60 minutes then the thread hangs at the `java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0` forever. Thread does not wait for the query to finish since the query is executed successfully as it can be seen from the Oracle DB running queries as i described

Comment: Method in the `CalculatorService` is annotated with the `@Transactional`. It does not work at all if that annotation is not present since there is no transaction in such case.

Comment: If the query (the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT... ` takes the same time in both cases then you cannot speed up things. That being said you are probably getting a timeout at a low level (tcp connection ) which basically kills the connection (on a tcp channel level).

Comment: Is there some way how the Hikari od JDBC can ping the connection periodically?

Comment: It is used so no. Also there could be another downstream component like a router or firewall bluntly terminating the connection after x time. Or the database itself for that matter.